Is it possible to use a langchain agent to retrieve data indexed with llamaIndex?
From my understanding, Langchain is better at making agents & LlamaIndex is better at indexing.
Is it possible to mix them? To use a langchain agent to retrieve data indexed with llamaIndex?

Have you tried? You're expected to make an attempt and show your code.

Yes, you can use a LangChain agent to retrieve data indexed with LlamaIndex. First, build and index your data using LlamaIndex, then load this index in your LangChain setup. Define a custom tool in LangChain that queries the index, and integrate it into an agent. Finally, run the agent to retrieve information from the indexed data using natural language queries. This setup allows efficient and powerful data retrieval using large language models.
